# How to exclude a word from a regular expression in oracle?

Tags: regex, oracle

I have table (Oracle DB) with some products:

```
product_1 150
product_2 250
product_1 test 150
product_3
... etc
```

I want take data only for “product_1” but not for “product_1 test” with **only one condition**. I use REGEXP_LIKE for it:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLENAME
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(LOWER(PRODUCT), '.*product_1.*(?!test).*')
```

But it does not work and return empty result. Where is mistake in syntax of regexp?

Comment: looks like your need `.*product_1\s+[0-9]+`

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan what for numbers in regexp? :) and where word for exclude?..

Comment: didn't get you... Did my comment's regex not worked? it should

Comment: Lookaheads are not supported by Oracle regexp.  Try `REGEXP_LIKE(LOWER(PRODUCT), 'product_1\s') and not REGEXP_LIKE(LOWER(PRODUCT), 'product_1\s+test')`

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan `.*product_1\s+[0-9]+` - it does not work :(

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff `REGEXP_LIKE(LOWER(PRODUCT), '.*product_1.*') AND NOT REGEXP_LIKE(LOWER(PRODUCT), '.*product_1.*test.*')` - it work correctly. But... because of specifics of the task I shall have **only one condition**. Therefore I also decided to use REGEXP instead couple of LIKE and NOT LIKE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oracle does not support lookaheads.
With the products as you show, you can use this:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLENAME WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(PRODUCT, 'product_\d+(\s*\d+)*', 'c');
```

This is only based on the product names you have shown. If it does not catch everything you want, give us a better idea of what we are trying to match.

Another option: it's a hack, but if you're confident that "product_digits " should never be followed by a "t", you can use this:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLENAME WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(PRODUCT, 'product_\d+($|\s)($|[^t]).*', 'c');
```

Answer (score 0):

Only one condition:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLENAME 
WHERE 
  REGEXP_INSTR(LOWER(PRODUCT), 'product_1\s') 
  > REGEXP_INSTR(LOWER(PRODUCT), 'product_1\s+test')
```